# Culture curiosity. Baloon with a wish

Tags: culture

It is a question more about culture than German language.

I live in Poland. Last week I found in my garden a balloon out of the gas.

On the balloon there was a drawing of a girl saying

> Viel Spaß mit Carina

There was a Sheet of paper with a wish fixed to it that says:

> Wir wünschen Euch einen gut funktionierenden Wecker, damit Ihr immer pünktlich zur Schule kommt.

Of course I can translate the saying on the sheet as a wish for a schoolchild for better functioning of his/her alarm clock that he/she can be at school on time.

I find myself this situation very funny and I wonder what cultural event It could be. Maybe Birthday? If the child was Christian, maybe Eucharist/Confirmation. If she was married at the age of 19 maybe it could be her wedding?

Do someone know this kind of tradition in Germany or Austria to leave flying balloons with wishes printed and fixed to them? I am very curious of it.

Comment: I would guess it is a school start. In some regions school holidays ended last week. Sometimes on weddings balloons are started, but I know it without cards. Balloons with cards are often uses as a challenge: The text is something like _Please send the card back and write where you found _. The card with the longest distance is th winner.

Comment: @knut Thank you very much. Now it is clear. I haven't earned enough reputation yet to up-vote your comment ;)

Comment: After reading Thomas answer: Maybe it is the wedding of Carina and the bridal pair are teachers?

Comment: When I was in primary school, we let balloons fly once as a reaction to a war that was going on somewhere else. And once, we simply did it to see who‘d receive an answer. It was always organized by our teachers.

Comment: Maybe Carina was a hamster, but the hamster fell off the balloon somewhere on the way.

Comment: @Philipp Ouch! Poor hamster ^_^!

Answer (score 8):

I'm pretty sure this is one of the wedding balloons.  It works like this: On the party the guests write these wishes (like the one you read on the card) for the bridal pair. They attach them to balloons and let them go. If you find this, you are supposed to drop it in a mailbox (add a stamp if there is no stamp) so that it comes back to them.  The address is hopefully already filled in.

One of the balloons from my wedding traveled over 800km and was mailed back from Austria.

So I guess Carina and whoever will be very happy if they get the postcard back from Poland.  Please send it!

Comment: Unfortunately there was no address information attached. Only the text I rewrote in question :(

Comment: Hmm, this is weird. Then I don't really know how to understand that balloon.